# Exclude duplicate nodes from when using the xsl:number

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

When using the Numbering function it actually gets the node position(). How to exclude items appearing more than once in the xml, from the numbering procedure ?
This is My simple xml demo:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="numbers.xsl"?>
<cars>
  <manufacturer name="Chevrolet">
    <car>Cavalier</car>
    <car>Cavalier</car>
    <car>Corvette</car>
    <car>Impala</car>
  </manufacturer>
  <manufacturer name="Ford">
    <car>Pinto</car>
    <car>Pinto</car>
    <car>Mustang</car>
    <car>Taurus</car>
  </manufacturer> 
</cars>
```

This is My xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>
 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:text>Automobile manufacturers and their cars&#xA;</xsl:text>
  <xsl:for-each select="cars/manufacturer">
   <xsl:text> Table_</xsl:text>
   <xsl:number count="manufacturer" format="A. ("/>
   <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
   <xsl:text>)&#xA;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:for-each select="car">
     <xsl:if test="not(preceding::*[car = current()/car])">
      <xsl:number count="car" level="any" format="  1. "/>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
     </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
   </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is the desired output:

Table_A. (Chevrolet)

1. Cavalier
2. Corvette
3. Impala

Table_B. (Ford)

4. Pinto
5. Mustang
6. Taurus

Thanks in advance

Comment: If different manufacturers have cars of the same name, would that count as a duplicate or would you need to to identify duplicates only in relation to a manufacturer?

Comment: Different manufacturers have not cars of the same name

Comment: Is your question not answered?

Answer (score 2):

First thing, in order to exclude duplicate values, you should be using [Muenchian grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html), not the inefficient method of comparing each car to all preceding cars (or rather all preceding sibling cars, in case two manufacturers have a similarly named model).

Next, `xsl:number` looks at the input tree - so if you want the numbering to follow the output, you will need to use a variable to hold the interim result. Try something along the lines of:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:key name="car" match="car" use="concat(., '|', ../@name)" />

<xsl:template match="/cars">
    <xsl:variable name="temp">
        <xsl:for-each select="manufacturer">
            <manufacturer name="{@name}">
                <!-- copy only distinct values -->
                <xsl:copy-of select="car[count(. | key('car', concat(., '|', ../@name))[1]) = 1]"/>
            </manufacturer>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
    <!-- output -->
    <xsl:for-each select="exsl:node-set($temp)/manufacturer">
        <xsl:text> Table_</xsl:text>
        <xsl:number count="manufacturer" format="A. ("/>
        <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
        <xsl:text>)&#xA;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:for-each select="car">
            <xsl:number count="car" level="any" format="  1. "/>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each> 
    </xsl:for-each> 
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Alternatively, if your processor supports it, you could use the EXSLT [set:distinct()](http://exslt.org/set/functions/distinct/index.html) extension function.

Comment: It dosn't work. Maybe I need something like :  <xsl:choose>
   <xsl:when test="function-available('exsl:node-set')">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="exsl:node-set($tables-rtf)/table"/>
   </xsl:when>
   <xsl:when test="function-available('msxml:node-set')">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="msxml:node-set($tables-rtf)/table"/>
   </xsl:when>
  </xsl:choose> ? distinct() also not working

Comment: You can see it working here: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6qjt5SF. If it doesn't work for you, then explain **exactly** what is the result you get with the same exact code. And which XSLT processor you are using.

Comment: If you are using a Microsoft processor, you may have to use their own `node-set()` extension function, in their own namespace - see: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6qjt5SF/1.