# Apply numbering by excluding duplicate nodes independently of processor status

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

Concerning my
[Exclude duplicate nodes from when using the xsl:number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72084610/exclude-duplicate-nodes-from-when-using-the-xslnumber/72085074?noredirect=1#comment127513469_72085074)
theme, I resulted in the following code:

```
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
  xmlns:msxml="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
  exclude-result-prefixes="exsl msxml"
  version="1.0">
 <xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>
 <xsl:key name="car" match="car" use="concat(., '|', ../@name)" />
  <xsl:template match="/cars">
   <xsl:variable name="temp">
    <xsl:for-each select="manufacturer">
     <manufacturer name="{@name}">
      <!-- copy only distinct values -->
      <xsl:copy-of select="car[count(. | key('car', concat(., '|', ../@name))[1]) = 1]"/>
     </manufacturer>
    </xsl:for-each>
   </xsl:variable>
   
  <!-- output -->
  <xsl:choose>
   <xsl:when test="function-available('exsl:node-set')">
   <xsl:for-each select="exsl:node-set($temp)/manufacturer">
    <xsl:text> Table_</xsl:text>
    <xsl:number count="manufacturer" format="A. ("/>
    <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
    <xsl:text>)&#xA;</xsl:text>
     <xsl:for-each select="car">
      <xsl:number count="car" level="any" format="  1. "/>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
     </xsl:for-each> 
    </xsl:for-each> 
   </xsl:when> 
   <xsl:when test="function-available('msxml:node-set')">  
    <xsl:for-each select="msxml:node-set($temp)/manufacturer">
    <xsl:text> Table_</xsl:text>
    <xsl:number count="manufacturer" format="A. ("/>
    <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
    <xsl:text>)&#xA;</xsl:text>
     <xsl:for-each select="car">
      <xsl:number count="car" level="any" format="  1. "/>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
     </xsl:for-each> 
   </xsl:for-each> 
   </xsl:when>
  </xsl:choose>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I still have two questions: First : Can repetitions in xsl:choose eliminated, still using for-each syntax and not apply-template?
Second: Is something more than 'exsl:node-set' and 'msxsl:node-set' that I am
missing to check concerning processors? Code has been checked in three computers without necessarily knowing their processors status. Besides, code must work globally independent of user's processor which is unknown to the programmer.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is your question not answered?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way you can eliminate (most of) the code duplication:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
xmlns:msxml="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:key name="car" match="car" use="concat(., '|', ../@name)" />

<xsl:template match="/cars">
     <xsl:variable name="temp">
        <xsl:for-each select="manufacturer">
         <manufacturer name="{@name}">
            <!-- copy only distinct values -->
            <xsl:copy-of select="car[count(. | key('car', concat(., '|', ../@name))[1]) = 1]"/>
         </manufacturer>
        </xsl:for-each>
     </xsl:variable>
    <!-- output -->
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="function-available('exsl:node-set')">
            <xsl:for-each select="exsl:node-set($temp)/manufacturer">
                <xsl:call-template name="output"/>
            </xsl:for-each> 
         </xsl:when>    
        <xsl:when test="function-available('msxml:node-set')">  
            <xsl:for-each select="msxml:node-set($temp)/manufacturer">
                <xsl:call-template name="output"/>
            </xsl:for-each> 
         </xsl:when>    
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="output">
    <xsl:text> Table_</xsl:text>
    <xsl:number count="manufacturer" format="A. ("/>
    <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
    <xsl:text>)&#xA;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:for-each select="car">
        <xsl:number count="car" level="any" format="    1. "/>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each> 
</xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am  afraid I did not understand your 2nd question.

Comment: Thanks for the first answer. As for the second one, I have realized that the use of :node-set depends on user's processor. So I have to check between 'msxml:node-set' and 'exsl:node-set' (all the time it worked for the 'msxml:node-set'). Is there a third possibility I have to check in my xsl:when element?

Comment: I don't think so, but I don't know which processors you intend to use. It seems you want this code to be run by user's browser - if so, I suggest you look into implementing  SaxonJS.